# How to test anchor's href with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, anchor, href, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my anchor tag. Once I click it, I want to see if the `window.location.href` is what I expect.

I've tried to render the anchor, click it, and then test `window.location.href`:

```js
test('should navigate to ... when link is clicked', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<a href="https://test.com">Click Me</a>);

  const link = getByText('Click Me');

  fireEvent.click(link);

  expect(window.location.href).toBe("https://www.test.com/");
});
```

I am expecting the test to pass, but instead the window.location.href is just `"http://localhost/"` meaning it is not getting updated for whatever reason. I even tried wrapping my expect with `await wait`, but that didn't work either. I can't find much information about testing anchors with `react-testing-library`. Maybe there is even a better way to test them than what I am doing. ‍♂️

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Jest uses jsdom to run its test. jsdom is simulating a browser, but it has some limitations. One of these limitations is the fact that you can't change the location. If you want to test that your link works, I suggest checking the `href` attribute of your `<a>`:

```js
expect(screen.getByText('Click Me').closest('a')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://www.test.com/')
```

**Update**

Nowadays is better to use `getByRole` if possible:

```js
expect(screen.getByRole('link', { name: 'Click Me' })).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://www.test.com/')
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: getByText(...).closest is not a function` any ideas?

Comment: I guess that `getByText` finds nothing in your case

Comment: I just had to add `screen`: `expect(screen.getByText('Click Me').closest('a')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://www.test.com/')`and worked like charm.

Comment: I had the same problem and adding import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
 to the top of the file fixed the problem

Comment: This is not as good as the answer from Dominic below, because of the search for `closest('a')`, it falls a bit outside of the spirit of react-testing-library ("The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you") imo. `getByRole('link')` aligns closer with the spirit of the library since no such search is required. Even if the spirit of the library is itself questionable lol. Note, I have not downvoted - just saying...

Comment: This did not work for me, I have this DOM: `<a  href="some-url">Next Step</a>`, I tried `expect(screen.getByText('Next Step').closest('a')).toHaveAttribute('href', "some-url")`. But got this error: 
`Expected the element to have attribute:
      href="some-url"
    Received:
      null`

Comment: If you do not want to install "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect" for one method call, then just use:        `screen.getByText('Click Me').getAttribute('href');
 expect(href).toBe('https://www.test.com/');`

Answer (score 95):

I found a solution that may help others.  The `<a>` element is considered a `link` role by React Testing Library.  This should work:

```
expect(screen.getByRole('link')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://www.test.com');
```

Comment: this is probably the best answer as in the RTL documentation it says querying by role gets the highest priorities in regards to queries.  [About Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about)

Comment: This will work only if there is only 1 link on the page

Comment: @Constantin If there are more links on the page, you need to use `getAllByRole()` and target the specific link you want.

Comment: You can also `.getByRole('link', { name: 'text of link' })`.

Answer (score 36):

If you are using `screen` which should be the preferred way, by RTL authors:

```
const linkEl = screen.getByRole('link', { name: 'Click Me' });

expect(linkEl).toHaveAttribute('href', '...')
```

Similar, without screen (name can be string or RegExp):

```
const linkEl = getByRole('link', { name: /click me/i });
```

Answer (score 23):

You can simply use this instead:

```
expect(getByText("Click Me").href).toBe("https://www.test.com/")
```

Comment: That does not prevent from a development bug where there's a prop href but no <a />. Think in dynamic components, for example, a button that renders as a link. Of course, it wouldn't make sense but to force failure on your tests you need to validate that the property href is being used in a link element.

Comment: you need to reference to screen , but even doing so you will get a type error because:
TS2339: Property 'href' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: In react this translates `/link` into `http://localhost/link` which causes the test to fail. Using `toHaveAttribute` works correctly.

Answer (score 8):

simple and easy.

**try this**

```
  it('should be a link that have href value to "/login"', () => {
    render(<SigningInLink />);
    const link = screen.getByRole('link', { name: /log in/i });
    expect(link.getAttribute('href')).toBe('/login');
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe its overtly engineered in this case. But you can also use data-testid attribute. This guarantees that you are getting the a tag. I think there are benefit to this for more complex components.

```
test('should navigate to ... when link is clicked', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<a data-testid='link' href="https://test.com">Click Me</a>);

  expect(getByTestId('link')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://test.com');
   
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use:

```
const linkToTest = screen.getByRole("link", { name: /link to test/i })
// I used regex here as a value of name property which ignores casing

expect(linkToTest.getAttribute("href")).toMatchInlineSnapshot();
```

and then run the test, brackets of `toMatchInlineSnapshot` will be filled with the value that's there in your code.

This has the advantage of not hard coding it, and maintaining this will be easier.

For eg: it will be filled like this:

```
expect(linkToTest.getAttribute("href")).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"link/to/somewhere"`);
```

and next time, suppose you change this link to something else in your codebase, the runner will ask you if you want to update, press `u` and it will be updated. (Note, that you need to check that this update is correct).

Know more about inline snapshots on [Jest Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing#inline-snapshots)

Answer (score 5):

You may have several links to check on a page. I found these suggestions very useful. What I did to adapt it to checking 5 links on the same page -

1. query the link on the page with the `screen()` method best practice - it is more reliable
2. assert the link is on the page
3. assign the link to a variable
4. call event on the link
5. ensure the url `toHaveAttribute` method rather than navigating with the window object - In react with the virtual DOM, if you try and navigate to another page the link directs to  http://localhost/link rather than testing the redirect

```
test('should navigate to url1 when link is clicked', () => {

const componentName = render(<Component/>)

const url1 = getByText("https://www.test.com/")
expect(ur1).toBeInTheDocument()
screen.userEvent.click(url1);
expect(url1).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://www.test.com/')

});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
expect(screen.getByText('Click Me').closest('a')?.href).toEqual('https://test.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, works for me using testing-library/react

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import {HomeFeature} from '../Components/HomeFeature.tsx';

let imp_content = [
    {
        title: "Next.js",
        link: "https://nextjs.org/",
    },
    {
        title: "React",
        link: "https://reactjs.org/",
    },
    {
        title: "Firebase",
        link: "https://firebase.google.com/",
    },
    {
        title: "Tailwind",
        link: "https://tailwindcss.com/",
    },
    {
        title: "TypeScript",
        link: "https://www.typescriptlang.org/",
    },
    {
        title: "Jest.js",
        link: "https://jestjs.io/",
    },
    {
        title: "testing-library/react",
        link: "https://testing-library.com/",
    }
];

imp_content.map((content) => {
    test(`${content.title} contains ${content.link}`, () => {
        render(<HomeFeature />);
        expect(screen.getByText(content.title).closest('a')).toHaveAttribute('href', content.link);
    })
})
```

Comment: Hello I would like to point out that your answer violates the eslint-plugin-testing-library/no-node-access rule due to using .closest to access nodes when the library already provides methods for querying DOM elements.