# To Test the result of an <a href=... click

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm just looking for a sanity-check on a React unit test I'm writing.

I have the simplest of simple react components:

```
export function SiteLogo() {
  return (
    <a data-testid="SiteLogo-anchor" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news">
      <img src={logo} />
    </a>
  );
}
```

A site logo. The user clicks it and gets redirected someplace. The BBC link is hardwired just until I get everything working, just to be obvious.

My problem is that I want to unit test this, in particular the wiring. Just a bog-standard unit test using a combination of jest and react testing library. I'm new to these particular libraries, pretty new to react overall, and this trivial task seems to have become overcomplicated.

I have:

```
test("Test Homepage Logo click redirects to site homepage", () => {
  render(<SiteLogo />);
  const anchor = screen.getByTestId("SiteLogo-anchor");
  expect(anchor).toBeDefined(); // passes
  fireEvent.click(anchor);
  // Now where?  
});
```

Where I'm at seems to be working, but what now?
I'm assuming fireEvent will actually start loading the new page. There'll then be a delay while the page loads. For now, I could hard-wire a 5s sleep in there, just to get it working, but... ugh. Once the page is loaded, ideally I'd like to check the value of the new URL, but I can live with checking that some particular content exists in the resulting document.

I'm second-guessing myself here. This seems to be too-many lines of code for a trivial action. So, am I doing this all wrong? I'm not particularly wanting to introduce another library here, but would one maybe be more intuitive?

Comment: I guess you can get an event out of the fireEvent call and get information from that event, can't you ?

Comment: @Billuc I looked along that route but my answer is that I'm not sure. As far as I can tell, fireEvent returns void. I could be wrong.

Comment: Hmm that is annoying... I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57827126/how-to-test-anchors-href-with-react-testing-library. Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: @Billuc in the end I discovered that userEvent.Click helped. Same kind of approach as Mr CK's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using fireEvent.click, you can use userEvent.click, which is more similar to how a real user interects with your app and you can await it. It would look something like this:

```
const user = userEvent.setup()
test("Test Homepage Logo click redirects to site homepage", async () => {
  render(<SiteLogo />); 
  const anchor = screen.getByTestId("SiteLogo-anchor");
  expect(anchor).toBeDefined(); // tobeDefined() is a weak check, you mostly want to use toBeVisible.
  await user.click(anchor);
  const titleOfTheNewScreen = screen.getByText('theTitleOfThePage'); // Or anything else that is visible.
  expect(titleOfTheNewScreen).toBeVisible();
});
```

it might not be enough to await the click action. It only awaits the async events triggered by the click. In this case you can use waitFor(), like this:

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.getByText('theTitleOfThePage')).toBeVisible();
})
```

This will wait until the element is visible and should throw a timeout otherwise. (you can also await findByText, which is sometimes more useful).

using a timeout in a unit test should almost always be avoided.

This might feel like a lot of lines, but it is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks Mr CK, sorry I don't have the rep to upvote yet. This was indeed the mechanism I discovered about an hour before I started on my christmas break!